# Correlation coefficient for any given matrix in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, matrix

Suppose I got a matrix that looks like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *
   FROM ( values
          (1, 4, 10),
          (2, 8, 20),
          (3, -2, 50) as dummy (a,b,c)
)
```

I'm trying to come up with a solution that would allow me to calculate correlation coefficient for any given x*x matrix. I know that SQL isn't the right tool for the job, but I'm still trying to make something out of it.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? I tried using dynamic pivot, but it seems not to work.

Comment: A Pearson correlation coefficient? There doesn't seem to be any math going on here, so what have you tried?

Comment: I don't speak math, but according to wiki it's usually about two variables. what are you correlating in a matrix?

Comment: *"I know that SQL isn't the right tool for the job"* I too, dont speak math, but you're right that SQL seems like the wrong tool. It seems like you want a analytics tool of some kind

Comment: @siggemannen I'm looking for sth akin to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Answer (score 2):

The math is not complicated provided a normalized structure

Results verified at https://www.statskingdom.com/correlation-calculator.html

**Example**

```
Declare @Data Table (Col1 float,Col2 float );
Insert Into @Data Values
(6.37, 5.13),
(6.73, 5.44),
(5.66, 4.42),
(5.69, 4.31),
(5.87, 4.49),
(5.50, 4.00),
(6.36, 4.96),
(7.45, 6.25),
(6.21, 4.70),
(6.77, 5.30),
(7.08, 5.72),
(6.41, 4.85),
(7.13, 6.01),
(6.88, 5.83),
(6.95, 5.61);

Select Correlation = (Avg(Col1 * Col2) - Avg(Col1) * Avg(Col2)) / (StDevP(Col1) * StDevP(Col2)) FROM @Data;
```

**Results**

```
Correlation
0.9808880347865
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to calculate correlation matrix for any given number of variables. 
This would work for pair-wise combinations, but suppose I have 10 variables? I am looking for something akin to numpy.corrcoeff.